# Uninstalling MS voice not possible

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, uninstall

In order to reproduce a bug with the Voices (available through SAPI) in Windows, I exported a registry key from a customer's computer and imported it on my computer.

Namely it was

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0
```

I tried to remove the registry key again, but Windows wouldn't let me as only TrustedInstaller can do that as it's a part of the English Windows system.

I tried remote-acessing the registry via PS, but that wouldn't work either.
I installed the English language package for Windows 10, and that installed another TTS_MS_EN_US voice, so I think it tried to install ZIRA as well.

When I removed this language package, the other MS_EN_US was gone, but ZIRA was still there.

When I take ownership of the key, and I try to delete the key, it says "TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0 can't be deleted. Error trying to delete key."
And ProcMon simply outputs "CANNOT DELETE" without any further information.

Does anybody have ANY other idea how I could remove this voice from the registry?

Comment: You should be able to just take ownership of the key and then delete it.

Comment: When I try to give permissions to "User", it says "Permission options for TTS_MS_EN-US ZIRA_11.0 were not saved. Access denied."

Comment: @Ramhound And when I really take ownership, and I try to delete the key, it says "TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0 can't be deleted. Error trying to delete key."

Comment: And ProcMon simply says: "CANNOT DELETE"